# TString -> Array of Variant

Tags: delphi, массивы, delphi-xe

Есть список параметров в TString и процедура, которой они нужны, но она их ждёт в виде Array of Variant

```
procedure MyProc(mParam:array of variant);
var
  num:Integer;
begin
  for num := 0 to Length(mParam)-1 do
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Append('mParam['+IntToStr(num)+'] = '+mParam[num]);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a:TStrings;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  a:=TStringList.Create;
  a.Append('string_1');
  a.Append('string_2');
  a.Append('string_3');
  a.Append('string_4');
  a.Append('string_5');

  //MyProc(a);

  a.Free;
end;
```

**Можно ли ему как-то красиво при передаче поменять тип, чтобы процедура смогла его корректно принять?**

Там есть такие методы, как a.ToObjectArray, a.ToStringArray например...
Но у меня через них не вышло... Или может что-то типа `TArray<Variant>(a)`?

Пока сделал вот так:

```
var
  arrParam: Array Of Variant;
  Num:Integer;
...
  Num:=a.Count;
  SetLength(arrParam,Num);
  if Num>0 then
    for Num:=0 To Num-1 Do
      arrParam[Num]:=a[Num];
  MyProc(arrParam);
...
```

Работает как нужно, но как-то это не красиво(или не профессионально) и совсем мне не нравится (

Answer (score 1):

```
var
  arrParam: Array Of Variant;
  i: Integer;
...
  SetLength(arrParam, a.Count);
  for i := 0 to a.Count - 1 do
    arrParam[i] := a[i];
  MyProc(arrParam);
...
```

Расскажите лучше:

1. Для чего вам в вашей процедуре нужен `array of varant`? Почему не передать `TStringList`?
2. Почему бы не заполнять сразу `array of variant` вместо того, чтобы перекладывать из `TSringList` в массив вариантов?

Comment: я расскажу конечно) это просто упрощённый пример
1. потому, что это не моя процедура, а из библиотеки без исходного кода. Требует, как входной параметр array of varant
2. В виде TString получаю параметры из триггера от SQL, там вроде в виде array of varant тоже нет возможности передавать, только простые типы

Comment: @Isaev
Ну, в таком случае, придется перекладывать. Короче уже не придумаешь.

Можно еще проверку перед вызовом сделать сделать:

    if Length(arrParam) > 0 then
      MyProc(arrParam);

Comment: Грустно... Ну что ж, придётся оставить так, благодарю за участие